# Newbie sql transaction question: preventing race in read - compute -write

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I want to do the following in one transaction:

- read a column
- if the column value matches a certain condition, write out a new value to the column

transaction isolation is set to read-commited, server is SQL server.

How can I guarantee that another transaction does not write a different value to the column
after I read it? Will the server reject my write if another transaction changed the column?

In other words, can SQL server be used as a distributed lock on a given column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to use `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level. With `READ COMMITTED` another transaction can change your record.
If you can rewrite your logic in 1 query(for example, with `update` or `merge`), you can still use `READ COMMITTED`. But sometimes it's not the option. For instance,

```
SELECT ... ;
IF some_condition
BEGIN
  // execute a procedure, select from other tables, etc
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  // execute another procedure, do some other stuff
END;
// finally update the record
UPDATE ....
```

**Update**

There is another option I forgot to mention : use table hint `REPEATABLEREAD`  in your `SELECT` statement ([See](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) for details)

Answer (score 4):

Who said you have to read it first?

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET    yourcolumn = CASE
                      WHEN certaincondition = 1 THEN 'newvalue'
                      ELSE yourcolumn
                    END
WHERE  id = 'yourid'
```

You evaluate inside the `UPDATE` itself. It's guaranteed to be totally isolated. You can have multiple of this same `UPDATE` running from different instances, the transactions will be queued and processed one by one.